# Get page generated with Javascript in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, download, urllib2

I'd like to download web page generated by `Javascript` and store it to string variable in `Python` code. The page is generated when you click on button.

If I would know the resulting URL I would use `urllib2` but this is not the case.

thank you

Comment: Is this generated completly in js or just built from an ajax call ?

Comment: @e-satis I think that it's completely in js

Comment: Then I'd got with J.F solution, or with python webkit. Just keep in mind they require a display server to be running so if you plan to make it run on a headless server, you'll need to hack a little bit.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use [Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# use firefox to get page with javascript generated content
with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
     browser.get(url)
     button = browser.find_element_by_name('button')
     button.click()
     # wait for the page to load
     WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(
         lambda x: x.find_element_by_id('someId_that_must_be_on_new_page'))
     # store it to string variable
     page_source = browser.page_source
print(page_source)
```

Comment: is the `WebDriverWait` with `someId_that_must_be_on_new_page` neccessary? Could it be done only with some `sleep` or `delay` function? And is it possible to set the user-agent string?

Comment: There is one problem yet. On the web page is `select` element and something have to be selected. If nothing is selected the button won't work. And is neccessary to open and close firefox? Without `guit` this won't work?

Comment: you could use any condition you like e.g., `x.title == 'New Title'`. You probably could modify user-agent by using appropriate firefox profile.

Comment: here's an example on how to [select option](https://gist.github.com/1411564). `.quit()` is not necessary.

Comment: The method `select_option(self, selector, value)` takes `selector` parameter. I'm not sure what this parameter should be. Let's say I want to click on option with `value = 100` of `select` with `id = 'sel_id'` and `name = 'sel_name'`. Could this be expressed in `CSS`?

Comment: @xralf: `select_option('select#sel_id', '100')`. You could pass an element instead `select_option(browser.find_element_by_id('sel_id'), '100')`.

Comment: Thanks. I already used `options = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('option') for option in options:
       if option.get_attribute('value') == "100":
         option.click()` and worked too.

Comment: Can this done by opening Firefox window on the background?

Comment: @alper yes, there headless options