# Scraping iframe tag in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage using `python` , but the problem is that the scraped html contains just the `iframe` tag and not the actual `html` inside the `iframe` tag. Is there any way to get inner `html` of `iframe` tag in `python`?

Here's my iframe tag like

```
 <iframe id="popupFrame" src="#" style="visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why don't you scrape the `src` of the `iframe`?

Comment: `src="#"` . How do I scrape that?

Comment: That means that the content of the `iframe` is dynamically generated using JavaScript. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960567/reading-dynamically-generated-web-pages-using-python) on how to parse dynamic content.