# how to scraping text from hidden div and class using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i working on a script for scraping video titles from this webpage 
" https://www.google.com.eg/trends/hotvideos "
but the proplem is the titles are hidden on the html source page but i can see it if i used the inspector to looking for that

that's my code it's working good with this ("class":"wrap")
but when i used that with the hidden one like "class":"hotvideos-single-trend-title-container"  that's did't give me anything on output

```
#import urllib2
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://www.google.com.eg/trends/hotvideos').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print (soup.findAll('div',{"class":"hotvideos-single-trend-title-container"}))
#wrap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is generated/populated by using Javascript.

BeautifulSoup won't help you here, you need a library which supports Javascript generated HTML pages, see here for a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960567/reading-dynamically-generated-web-pages-using-python) or have a look at [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)