# How to let a webpage load before scraping with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a small Snow Day Calculator python program, and I figured that I could use BeautifulSoup to do the job. I am able to successfully scrape the page, HOWEVER I noticed that the result is always 0%. I then noticed that this is because it takes the website about a second or two after it loads to display the percentage, and this is because of the website's reactive javascript.

How would I be able to load the webpage, wait two-three seconds, and then scrape the webpage for the snow day percentage?

Code:

```
import urllib
import bs4

def getPercent(zip):
    url = "https://snowdaypredictor.com/result.html?q="+zip
    print url
    page = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
    name_box = soup.find('span', attrs = {'id': 'result-percent'})
    print name_box.text.strip(),"%"

getPercent(raw_input("What is your zip code?"))
```

Comment: you need https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash

Comment: Selenium python bindings might also be helpful. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading dynamically generated web pages using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960567/reading-dynamically-generated-web-pages-using-python)

Comment: I was able to get it working with selenium, thank you so much!