# How to scrape data from a table where the html is rendered by JavaScript? (Ideally in Python but open to other methods)

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I've been looking for a solution to scrape data from a table where the html dynamically changes as you scroll through the table. The html will only show the data that is actually displayed on screen in the browser.

What I have done so far is use Selenium to deal with the rendering of the html code. I have thought about trying to scroll through the table and collect the data in increments but 1) I cannot seem to actually scroll through the table using selenium as class names have spaces 2) I feel there must be a better way to grab all the data in one go.

Edit: This is not a duplicate question as suggested in the comments. I have no problem obtained html code rendered by JavaScript. But the JavaScript for the table I am referring to will only be executed if it needs to be i.e. if the table is scrolled and hence needs to be displayed on screen. What this means if I scroll through the table, the html code for the newly displayed rows will appear but the code for the previously displayed rows will disappear.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading dynamically generated web pages using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960567/reading-dynamically-generated-web-pages-using-python)

Comment: @nauer No. Please read the question carefully.