# Python website source extraction

Tags: python, html

i'm using `urllib2` to download the source of a website, but something is going wrong. 
The source comes from this website: http://www.starfm.com/
All i want to do is to download the entire html , and then parse it extracting the "Now playing" section from the website.

But, when i download the source with this code

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.starfm.com/')
html = response.read()
a = open("C:\\users\\Leonardo\\Desktop\\source.txt","w")
a.write(html)
a.close()
```

the final source does not show the current artist in the website's "Now playing" section.

Why? 
What should i do?

Thanks so much in advance.

-Leonardo

Comment: You missed the brackets on `a.close`. It should be `a.close()`.

Comment: Just copied from last command line try, the original source has brackets.

Comment: Visit that page with JavaScript disabled on your browser and you will answer your own question.

Comment: Yes i know that the problem is javascript, but i've tried with libs like http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html or http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/ and i was not able to do anything.

Could anyone tell me where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"now playing" comes from javascript, maybe it loads that info on the onload() event , in this case your code is just reading the content.

maybe this question will help you

[Get page generated with Javascript in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960288/get-page-generated-with-javascript-in-python)