# Refreshing an element only with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

I have a script that records a span field on a website using the requests module in python.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
while 1:
     print str(tree.xpath('//span[@id="ofr"]/text()')
```

However this span is updating and I am looking to refresh this without reloading the entire page, for which I cannot find a solution. Many thanks

Comment: requests is not a browser, it does not execute JavaScript that may be included in the page. It can only get the HTML of the page as is is *before* any client side JavaScript is executed. Can you tell, *how* the span is updated? What is happening on the client?

Comment: Thanks Lutz, the span is automatically refreshed, there's no interaction needed. Does that answer your question?Your comment did however point me in the right direction, I believe this is a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960288/get-page-generated-with-javascript-in-python

Comment: No, it does not. Automatically by what mechanism? JavaScript? A `refresh` meta tag?

Comment: it's a javascript element

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the requests.get call in the while 1, otherwise it no new request to the website is made. _lastValue holds the span's value from the last round and the scripts sleeps for one second between each lookups.

```
from lxml import html
import time
import requests

_lastValue  = None
while 1:
    r = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
    _currentValue = str(tree.xpath('//span[@id="ofr"]/text()')

    if _currentValue != _lastValue:
        print _currentValue
        _lastValue = _currentValue

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice, that was my initial approach, however this causes too much latency to reload the entire website. I am trying to read price data from an updating field.

Comment: This will not work because the page will probably be changed by client side JavaScript.

Comment: You need to reload the entire site, http protocol works like this (except the span changes via xhr/ajax requests)