# Cannot get generated html source using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to download the fully generated html source file for the following url: http://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/vinix/quote.html

In particular I am interested in extracting the generated numerical data in the table under the header "Performance VINIX", for instance, the row "Growth in 10,000". I have tried the approach outlined in [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960288/get-page-generated-with-javascript-in-python). But the saved text html file looks just like the pre-generated raw source file, with all the javascript and none of the generated content. For instance, when I grep for the word "Growth" I get nothing.

I have also gone through the DOM structure in chrome web devtools to identify the innermost element that contains this table, whose xpath is /html/body, and use the find_element_by_xpath technique to isolate the element, then saved the following string object:

```
content = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body').text
```

Still that did not work. Any idea why? Many thanks!

Comment: The xpath to the table under the header "Performance VINIX" is `/html/body`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get already generated table you need to wait a little until its presence in `DOM`. Also note that it is located inside `iframe` so you need to switch to that frame first before searching for required elements

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

wait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[starts-with(@id, "QT_IFRAME_")]')))
table = wait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "idPerformanceContent")))
```

Then you can scrape required data:

```
for i in table.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr[td="Growth of 10,000"]/td')[1:]:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andersson. As a front end novice there is little way I could have figured this out myself in 2 hours.